# Compare list with a second list in MS Azure sql

Tags: sql-server, azure

This is in Microsoft Azure. I have a list of reports that have specific organizations associated with it.  For example

```
CREATE TABLE Reports (
reportId INT,
OrganizationID INT
);

INSERT INTO Reports (reportId, OrganizationID) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(3, 3);
```

I also have a user table that's associated to organizations.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
User CHAR(1),
OrganizationId INT
);


INSERT INTO Users (User, OrganizationId) VALUES
('a', 1),
('a', 2),
('b', 2),
('c', 1),
('c', 2),
('c', 4);
```

What I need to do is figure out who has access to which report based on their organizations - the user has to have all the organizations that are listed in the report in order to have access to that report.  So with the above data I would expect to see user a has access to both report 1 and report 2, user b doesn't get access to any reports and user c gets access to report 1 and report 2.

Output example:

| User | ReportId |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |

I know I can use a SQL to loop through the reports one by one to figure out who has access to which report, is there a way to do that without looping through the reports and just in straight SQL?  Would appreciate any help!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You really need to provide an example  of the output to ensure that we don't get lost down tangents when the request is not 100% clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identfy if a user has permissions to all the organisations that a report covers, use a combination of `group by` and `having` clauses. Here it compares the number of organizations the user has to the number of organizations the report covers (note the join conditions requires the organizations to match per row).

```
SELECT
      r.reportId
    , u.User_
FROM Reports r
INNER JOIN Users u ON r.OrganizationID = u.OrganizationId
GROUP BY
      r.reportId
    , u.User_
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.OrganizationID) = (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrganizationID)
        FROM Reports r2
        WHERE r2.reportId = r.reportId
        )
```

| reportId | User_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |

see this SQL Server [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FLUDbJti)

Please note that the `having` clause is designed to allow for filtering via aggregated values. As such it sites after the `group by` clause and it is absolutely NOT a substitute for a `where` clause. You can use both in the same query.

Comment: The result needed is just userid and then reportid - what you are suggesting will show me user b and report 1 even though they only have one of the organizations listed. The user has to have all organizations associated in order to be affiliated with that report.

Comment: sorry - missed that detail - answer has been re-written.

Comment: Thank you - but I think that still won't work.  User c has three organizations associated (1,2,3) but the report only has 1 and 2 - user c should still get access because both of his orgs are in the report - I can't use count, because it won't necessarily be the same orgs even if the count is the same.

Comment: sorry - i edited user c to have a third org to show another scenario - if c has three orgs (1,2,4) he should still get access to report 1 and 2.  He also has 3 orgs and report 3 has 3 orgs - but even though the count will be the same, they're diff orgs, so he shouldn't get report 3.

Comment: The inner join forces only the rows that match to be considered, so it does not matter if a user has more orgs than a report does - but it does matter in reverse, so the query needs adjustment. The tables have been swapped, the join changed to left join, and the counts now use distinct.

Comment: Adrian - I don't think it solves the issue - the resultset shows user b getting report 1 and 3, which shouldn't happen at all, and users and c are getting report 3 - but nobody has 1,2,3 orgs so nobody should be getting report 3

Comment: Have tried a new approach using a subquery - please try this. Also go to https://dbfiddle.uk/RHQqNH6V I added another test case (user d)

Comment: That seems to work!  I'm going to play around with additional scenarios, but I think this sql is going to work.  Thank you!